# django models to work with database views,tables

Tags: database, django-models, view

My database has the tables books[isbn,name,author,availableNum],students[name,major,coursestaking],course[name,department,number,capacity,booksNeeded],department[name,courses]
I have a small view that has fields from all the above {courseName,booksRecommended,dept,countofstudents}.
When creating a model for view should I say something like this.

```
class Lookup(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey('course',db_column = 'name')
    booksRecommended = models.ForeignKey('books',db_column = 'isbn')
    dept = models.ForeignKey('department',db_column = 'name')
    studentcount = models.IntegerField()
```

I'm getting the error ProgrammingError: column lookup.id does not exist. Ideas are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `models.Model` that you have inherited from assumes that the table (or the view, in your case) has a column called as `id` that is used as a primary key, unless you have explicitly marked some other column to be `primary_key = True`.

Your view's sql, or the `./manage.py inspectdb` should help us find the primary key for this view.

Comment: this view doesn't have a primary key.so when i did ./manage.py inspectdb i couldnt see. but making one of the column(which was unique) to primary_key=True, did solve the issue.Thanks Lakshman

Comment: but in the views should i specify the relation explicitly, or as the database view already is aware of the constraints do i have to worry about it?

Comment: If the name of the primary key is id, django can guess it, otherwise, you need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: The fact I missed this autoId pattern caused me to lose some time. Adding `primary_key = True` to any field on the model for the view that will always be not null not blank solved it!